# How to escape characters when using Jquery serialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, escaping

I have a form page which I need to do some AJAX stuff prior to submitting, and I'm using serialize to [parse it, however form input names have period characters in them (nothing I can do about this, its a CRM quirk) which is breaking the ajax - how can I escape them in this case? Basically form is:

```
<form action="http://content.stuff.com" id="myid" class="form" method="POST" name="PPCform" >
<input name="uPEw.zMtH4.ptrq8qzoLXcwu7t87tfw2u" type="hidden" /> 
<input name="yP7h.zGDK46p8rq8qzJYDnru9D87Zfw2y" placeholder="Email"  type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" id="button-blue" value="SUBMIT AND CONTINUE" />
</form>
```

And the script is:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
    //FB pixel, other stuff
     $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize())
                        .done(function () {
                            // redirect, etc.
                        });
            });
```

But this doesn't work due to the . in the names. Since I'm not individually grabbing them I cant use the usual // escape method. Any idea how to instruct the serialize to escape the periods?

Comment: What do you mean by *"breaking the ajax"*?

Comment: Just gave this a quick try and the values are serialised and submitted correctly, eg `yP7h.zGDK46p8rq8qzJYDnru9D87Zfw2y=email@example.com`

Answer (score -2):

You can use a regex replace to simply remove the periods that are contained in the input names like such:

```
var serial = $(this).serialize().replace(/\.(?!com|net|org|us)/g,'')
$.post($(this).attr('action'), serial).done(function () {
    //Your code goes here.
});
```

It's a dead simple way of fixing the problem, but probably needs a lot more refinement on the regex side of things.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ny8Lf1x/1/)

Comment: Sorry, this is a terrible solution. Why would I want to remove characters from my input? I want to *escape* it.